# Windows: Does admin have access local disk to pc that joined AD server?

Tags: windows, active-directory, window

I'm new to windows, I have a question that if I have a pc and that pc joined and AD windows server, does admin have full access to my pc, even though he/she doesn't have my password, for example: access to local disk and get files on the pc, install whatever softwares they want?

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes;  If the PC is joined to the domain, then any user on the domain, can log into the machine.  Additionally, the domain administrator could, remotely connect to the machine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short yes. The AD administrator(s) has full administrative access to that machine, and to your files. If the AD Admin wanted or needed to, they could also remove your privileges, and make adjustments without your knowledge or permission.